# how parsing local json in android

Tags: android

i want json from local that method is post and server is nodejs.
i test below ip in postman and it work corectly:
http://10.127.127.1:8000/get_groups
(this ip is my local system)

but when i set this ip in android code, it not work and i dont have any error.

what is my problem?

below is my local address in android to connect:

```
public class ClsVars {

  public static String get_url(int code){


      String url="http://10.127.127.1:8000/";
      switch (code){
          case 1:

              url+="get_groups";
              break;
      }
      return url;
  }
}
```

and below code is my request class:

```
void get_groups(){


        String url=mylib.ClsVars.get_url(1);

        final StringRequest stringRequest=new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,

                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                       Log.i("resp", response);
//                              prog.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
//
//                              json_hash(response,hashMaps);
//                                 myAd.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        ///  Log.i("fragment Home", "-----------------------------------------response  not    ok");
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

//                          prog.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                           Log.i("err",error.getMessage());

                    }
                }

        ){

            @Override
            protected Map<String,String>getParams()throws AuthFailureError {


                Map<String, String> map = new Hashtable<String, String>();
                map.put("name", Base64.encodeToString("".getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT));
                return map;
            }

        };

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(ActGroups.this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }
```

finally below is logcat that it has not error:

```
09-16 14:52:25.563 2183-2183/? E/libprocessgroup: failed to make and chown /acct/uid_10077: Read-only file system
09-16 14:52:25.563 2183-2183/? W/Zygote: createProcessGroup failed, kernel missing CONFIG_CGROUP_CPUACCT?
09-16 14:52:25.563 2183-2183/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
09-16 14:52:25.701 2183-2183/com.example.hosseinry.tour W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=x86 --instruction-set-features=smp,-ssse3,-sse4.1,-sse4.2,-avx,-avx2 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=x86 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.example.hosseinry.tour-1/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/x86/data@app@com.example.hosseinry.tour-1@split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
09-16 14:52:25.898 2183-2183/com.example.hosseinry.tour W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=x86 --instruction-set-features=smp,-ssse3,-sse4.1,-sse4.2,-avx,-avx2 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=x86 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.example.hosseinry.tour-1/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/x86/data@app@com.example.hosseinry.tour-1@split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
09-16 14:52:25.920 2183-2183/com.example.hosseinry.tour W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=x86 --instruction-set-features=smp,-ssse3,-sse4.1,-sse4.2,-avx,-avx2 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=x86 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.example.hosseinry.tour-1/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/x86/data@app@com.example.hosseinry.tour-1@split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
09-16 14:52:25.944 2183-2183/com.example.hosseinry.tour W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=x86 --instruction-set-features=smp,-ssse3,-sse4.1,-sse4.2,-avx,-avx2 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=x86 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.example.hosseinry.tour-1/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/x86/data@app@com.example.hosseinry.tour-1@split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
09-16 14:52:25.995 2183-2183/com.example.hosseinry.tour W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=x86 --instruction-set-features=smp,-ssse3,-sse4.1,-sse4.2,-avx,-avx2 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=x86 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.example.hosseinry.tour-1/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/x86/data@app@com.example.hosseinry.tour-1@split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
09-16 14:52:26.021 2183-2183/com.example.hosseinry.tour W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=x86 --instruction-set-features=smp,-ssse3,-sse4.1,-sse4.2,-avx,-avx2 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=x86 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.example.hosseinry.tour-1/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/x86/data@app@com.example.hosseinry.tour-1@split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
09-16 14:52:26.042 2183-2183/com.example.hosseinry.tour W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=x86 --instruction-set-features=smp,-ssse3,-sse4.1,-sse4.2,-avx,-avx2 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=x86 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.example.hosseinry.tour-1/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/x86/data@app@com.example.hosseinry.tour-1@split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
09-16 14:52:26.073 2183-2183/com.example.hosseinry.tour W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=x86 --instruction-set-features=smp,-ssse3,-sse4.1,-sse4.2,-avx,-avx2 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=x86 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.example.hosseinry.tour-1/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/x86/data@app@com.example.hosseinry.tour-1@split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
09-16 14:52:26.095 2183-2183/com.example.hosseinry.tour W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=x86 --instruction-set-features=smp,-ssse3,-sse4.1,-sse4.2,-avx,-avx2 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=x86 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.example.hosseinry.tour-1/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/x86/data@app@com.example.hosseinry.tour-1@split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
09-16 14:52:26.114 2183-2183/com.example.hosseinry.tour W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=x86 --instruction-set-features=smp,-ssse3,-sse4.1,-sse4.2,-avx,-avx2 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=x86 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.example.hosseinry.tour-1/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/x86/data@app@com.example.hosseinry.tour-1@split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
09-16 14:52:26.134 2183-2183/com.example.hosseinry.tour W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=x86 --instruction-set-features=smp,-ssse3,-sse4.1,-sse4.2,-avx,-avx2 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=x86 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.example.hosseinry.tour-1/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/x86/data@app@com.example.hosseinry.tour-1@split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
09-16 14:52:26.136 2183-2183/com.example.hosseinry.tour W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.hosseinry.tour-1/lib/x86
09-16 14:52:26.138 2183-2183/com.example.hosseinry.tour I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
09-16 14:52:26.191 2183-2183/com.example.hosseinry.tour W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
09-16 14:52:26.331 2183-2221/com.example.hosseinry.tour D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
09-16 14:52:26.429 2183-2221/com.example.hosseinry.tour D/libEGL: loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_emulation.so
09-16 14:52:26.430 2183-2221/com.example.hosseinry.tour D/libEGL: loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so
09-16 14:52:26.442 2183-2221/com.example.hosseinry.tour D/libEGL: loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so
09-16 14:52:26.471 2183-2221/com.example.hosseinry.tour I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
09-16 14:52:26.580 2183-2221/com.example.hosseinry.tour W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
09-16 14:52:26.580 2183-2221/com.example.hosseinry.tour W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xe80bbf40, error=EGL_SUCCESS
09-16 14:52:26.710 2183-2183/com.example.hosseinry.tour W/art: Before Android 4.1, method int android.support.v7.widget.DropDownListView.lookForSelectablePosition(int, boolean) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.widget.ListView
```

where is my problem?
(i am new)

Comment: I am wondering why are you not using retrofit library?

Comment: Btw regarding error, I am seeing your are using POST, while API seems to have GET

Comment: but i am new in android and i want learn how to work with volley? can u help me?

Comment: what is solution? how can i use post? @dex

Comment: this is volley library tutorial: https://www.androidhive.info/2014/09/android-json-parsing-using-volley/